# Ok to connect micro usb to hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I just noticed that micro-usb (the one most of us use to charge our mobiles) fits perfectly in the hard disk port (images of both below).

[image: Hard disk port]

[image: Micro USB]

Will it be ok to use a micro-usb to usb cable for data transfer between a laptop and a hard disk?

Comment: Yuuuup!  It's fine

Comment: BTW,  what you are calling a "hard disk" port is actually a USB 3.0 port, and it is backwards compatible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. The port on the HD is the same Micro USB type-B, only with additional USB 3.0 pins on the side – it will still work with an USB 2 cable, but at a lower speed (the USB 2 maximum is ~48 MB/s).